# How to read and display json data

Tags: jquery, json

I have following json data.

```
{
  "movies": [{
  "id": "770687943",
  "title": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2",
  "year": 2011,
  "mpaa_rating": "PG-13",
   "runtime": 130,
   "critics_consensus": "Thrilling, powerfully acted, and visually dazzling, Deathly Hallows Part II brings the Harry Potter franchise to a satisfying -- and suitably magical -- conclusion.",
  "release_dates": {"theater": "2011-07-15"},
  "ratings": {
  "critics_rating": "Certified Fresh",
  "critics_score": 97,
  "audience_rating": "Upright",
  "audience_score": 93
},
"synopsis": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2, is the final adventure in the Harry Potter film series. The much-anticipated motion picture event is the second of two full-length parts. In the epic finale, the battle between the good and evil forces of the wizarding world escalates into an all-out war. The stakes have never been higher and no one is safe. But it is Harry Potter who may be called upon to make the ultimate sacrifice as he draws closer to the climactic showdown with Lord Voldemort. It all ends here. -- (C) Warner Bros",
"posters": {
  "thumbnail": "http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/15/86/11158674_mob.jpg",
  "profile": "http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/15/86/11158674_pro.jpg",
  "detailed": "http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/15/86/11158674_det.jpg",
  "original": "http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/15/86/11158674_ori.jpg"
},
"abridged_cast": [
  {
    "name": "Daniel Radcliffe",
    "characters": ["Harry Potter"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Rupert Grint",
    "characters": [
      "Ron Weasley",
      "Ron Wesley"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Emma Watson",
    "characters": ["Hermione Granger"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Helena Bonham Carter",
    "characters": ["Bellatrix Lestrange"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Ralph Fiennes",
    "characters": ["Lord Voldemort"]
  }
],
"alternate_ids": {"imdb": "1201607"},
"links": {
  "self": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770687943.json",
  "alternate": "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/harry_potter_and_the_deathly_hallows_part_2/",
  "cast": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770687943/cast.json",
  "clips": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770687943/clips.json",
  "reviews": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770687943/reviews.json",
  "similar": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770687943/similar.json"
}
}],
 "links": {
  "self": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?limit=1&country=us",
  "alternate": "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/movie/box_office.php"
 },
"link_template":  "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?limit={num-results}&country={country-code}"
}
```

The only thing I need from above json output is `image` which inside `poster` object named `profile`. Second `title`. Third ratings i.e. `critics_score` and `audience_score` which are inside `rating` object. The way I am reading this with my `underscorejs` template engine is following

```
<% _.each(movies, function(movie) { %>
<% var imdb_id; %>
<div class="boxone">
    <% _.each(movie, function (poster) { %>
        <img class="poster" src="<%= poster.profile %>" />
    <% }); %>
    <h4><%= movie.title %></h4>
    <p>
        <span>Up vote: </span>
        <% _.each(movie, function (rating) { %>
            <%= rating.audience_score %>
        <% }); %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <span>Down vote: </span>
        <% _.each(movie, function (rating) { %>
            <%= rating.critics_score %>
        <% }); %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <% _.each(movie, function (alternate_ids) { %>
            <% imdb_id = alternate_ids.imdb; %>
            <%= imdb_id %>
        <% }); %>
        <span>ID: </span><%= imdb_id %>
        <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt<% imdb_id %>">IMDB</a>
    </p>

</div>
<% }); %>
```

**Problem**

The problem with my current code is that when I want to read and display `profile` image inside `poster` object, I use first inside `each()` function then it creates several empty img tags. Same goes with other two inside each functions. **Is there better way to read above json data if yes the how?**

Comment: anyone who could help?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?